# How do you Rebase an immutable changeset with Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, rebase

I'm trying to rebase some changes I pulled in to my local machine. I'm getting the error:

```
abort: can't rebase immutable changeset 110e73ed65a4
(see hg help phases for details)
```

And I get the same error even after I change the phase on the changesets that I'm rebaseing (and the phase change seems to be successful). using:

```
hg phase -f -d REV
```

I'm wondering if there's a changeset in the history that I'm missing and is still immutable, and if so, if there is a way that I can change all of the changesets in a changeset's history to be mutable with a single command.

Or, is there a way to force rebase, even with the immutable changesets?

Comment: See http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#revsets for how to specify multiple changesets, e.g. `hg phase -f -d REVA::REVB`.  Note that even though you can `--force` phases all you like, Mercurial prevents you from ever having a public changeset whose ancestor is secret or draft.  So in any situation where you type `hg phase -f -d REV` then both `REV` and *all it's ancestors* must be have been public before you entered command, and the command only changes `REV`.  On the other hand, a single `hg phase -f -d BASE_REV` will affect all the descendants too, and `hg rebase` should work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rebasing changes that are public is considered a [very bad idea](http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2012/02/to-rebase-or-not-to-rebase-that-is.html). You shouldn't change any history that's been pushed -- the point of [phases](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Phases) is to track what changes haven't been pushed yet (so they're able to be modified), and what changes have been pushed (so they're immutable). From the [rebase documentation](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/RebaseExtension):

> You should not rebase changesets that have already been shared with others. Doing so will force everybody else to perform the same rebase or they will end up with duplicated changesets after pulling in your rebased changesets.

It's better to either merge in your changes or [graft](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/graft) them in. Graft (also known as cherry-picking) takes one or more changesets and copies them to your current branch.

Comment: my experience is that changesets can be considered immutable without having been pushed. if you have two local machines pulling your changes between eachother, they can be considered "pushed", even though they aren't

Comment: Rebase supports the `--keep` option. Commits rebased like this contain different metadata from graft - they show up differently.